# iPhone SDK Zoom and refresh PDF with Quartz

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics

Looking at the QuartzDemo sample application, I love the speed of the PDF rending using quartz alone (that is, without using uiwebview).  However, when I'm zooming in the PDF it doesn't seem to become more clear like it does in PDF view.

Is there something that I can change to have the same effect when zooming in and out using multitouch? like manipulate the PDF transformation matrix or something?

Thanks a bunch.

--Ben

Answer (score 1):

To make it zoom, and more clear, 
You can use CATiledLayer. You can see the following example.

http://www.olivetoast.com/blog/hamish/simple_uiscrollview_catiledlayer_example.ot

Comment: updated Link  http://www.olivetoast.com/blog/hamish/simple_uiscrollview_catiledlayer_example.ot